# ios watchkit app not able to install into iwatch using Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, xcode7.2

I'm new to working with Apple watch. I'm trying to install the hello world watchkit app into iwatch OS Version(1.0) that has been paired with my iPhone5c OSversion(9.1). When I try to choose the Build target device from the list of devices in Xcode it clearly shows that "Unavailable device" target. Below is the error message.

I did mouse over on the The OS version installed on watch apple watch doesn’t support Watchkit Extention products. Please see the below image for your reference. I would like to know what is the exact issue here and how can I fix it by steps and attach the device with Xcode 7.2 to run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the OS on your `Apple Watch` is lower than it'll support for testing, they changed some of the API in `Watch OS v2`. If you update to `OS v2` you should be able to use it for development.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll check and revert you soon.